# Reading multiple files from Snowflake Stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Based on Snowflake [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-internal-tutorial-copy-into.html), I am trying to just read the files but not copy into activity but not successful so far. So, it would be great if someone could please help me with this. If I hard-code a specific file, I am able to read each file individually but I want to read all of them together.

Here are the list of files I have in my stage.

```
contacts_20200101.csv.gz
contacts_20200102.csv.gz
contacts_20200103.csv.gz
contacts_20200104.csv.gz
contacts_20200105.csv.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view data in multiple files by querying the metadata of the files in a directory. If you specify a directory location instead of a file you will be able to see data in all the files of the directory.
Example:

```
(SELECT metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number, t.$1,t.$2,t.$3,t.$4,t.$5,t.$6,t.$7,t.$8
        FROM @YOURSTAGE/filedirectory/
        AS t);
```

Additionally if you have different file types in the same directory you can use a PATTERN in your statement:

```
(SELECT metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number, t.$1,t.$2,t.$3,t.$4,t.$5,t.$6,t.$7,t.$8
FROM @YOURSTAGE/filedirectory/
(PATTERN => '.*contact.*[.]csv.gz'
) t);
```

To add a date filter to your PATTERN statement you can do something similar to this:

```
(PATTERN => '.*contacts_2020[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*[.]csv.gz'
```

Comment: Thank you but what is the pattern for date here? I am not able to do the date pattern.

Comment: @Julaayi I updated my answer to include how to add a date pattern. The Pattern statement uses regex so you can modify it to your needs. If this answer was helpful please consider accepting it. If you need more info I can help further.